# What's Islam thinks of the bible?

Tags: bible

What does Islam think of the bible (both: old and new testament)?

According to Islam is it fake or authentic? (many stories in the bible aren't the same as in the Quran)

Kindly, support your answer with literature.

Answer (score 1):

Current bible are no book like Quran which is a miracle to Prophet Muhammad(S) from Allah, the direct saying of God. Instead bible are referenced to different authors. For old testaments, some are written by various school of thoughts(like the Pentateuch) from the early oral traditions, some are navim(writting from prophets, like hadith in islamic source), some are stories and poems. So there are ovious human interventions, so corruption is inevitable. Also some of them are documented in much later times. The main revelations by god are only known to the messengers, they used those to teach people.
For new testament, Jesus himself is the word of God according to quran and bible itself, he was strengthen by Ruh ul Kuddus(Gabriel (A)), So his saying was inspired and monitored by god in the presence of Gabriel(A). The new testaments of Jesus are small collection of his sayings. Probably he also received some official revelations from God as Injil what was only known to him and used them to teach the deciple. Or his saying are itself are the Injil where some of the revelation from god interpreted from Jesus's own mouth and ways.